# sharepoint list column in jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

How to user sharepoint list columns in Jquery. Can anyone please provide me an example of reading sharepoint list columns.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another open source project that might be useful for you is mine: [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com). The docs have plenty of examples.

> This is a jQuery library which
>   abstracts SharePoint's Web Services
>   and makes them easier to use. It also
>   includes functions which use the
>   various Web Service operations to
>   provide more useful (and cool)
>   capabilities. It works entirely client
>   side and requires no server install.

Comment: Ha - thats the one I was looking for and couldn't for the life of me remember what it was called! +1 internets from me.

Answer (score 0):

This open source project may help you - [Codeplex - JPoint](http://jpoint.codeplex.com/)

> Point is an open source javascript API
>   and script deployment framework for
>   Sharepoint. It leverages the speed and
>   agility of jQuery to manipulate
>   Sharepoint forms and pages,
>   communicate to Sharepoint webservices,
>   and to build jPart plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer simplicity in code, and if you'd like, I feel that you can get a much larger understanding of functionality by writing the code yourself. I suggest, depending on your sharepoint version, using the REST interface with the listdata.svc web service. Here's the code for reading data from a list "employees".

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $.getJSON('<insert relative url to site containing list>/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/employees', function(data){
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, value){
      alert(value.<columnName>);
    });
  });
});
```